# Using cmake to staticlly link to the C++ AWS SDK in linux fails by linking to a shared object file

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, aws-sdk

I wish to build a c++ static executable to run in a docker alpine linux image. I have a requirement to link the AWS SDK in order to use their services. When linking dynamic everything works fine however I wish to static link to keep my docker image size down.

How do I tell cmake to use the .a file and not the .so file? This is the error I'm getting:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable Server
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: attempted static link of dynamic object `/usr/lib/libcurl.so'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Projects/Server/CMakeFiles/Server.dir/build.make:220: Projects/Server/Server] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:146: Projects/Server/CMakeFiles/Server.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
/app # rm -Rf build/^C
```

Here is the line I'm using to build my project:

```
cmake\
    ../..\
    -DCMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES=".a"\
    -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS="-static"\
    -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF\
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-pthread"\
    -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++\
    -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc

make -j4
```

Here is a cut down version of my CMakeLists:

```
project(Server)

file(GLOB source_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB header_files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")

add_executable(Server ${source_files} ${header_files})

target_include_directories(
    Server
    PRIVATE
)

find_package(AWSSDK REQUIRED COMPONENTS core s3 sqs)

target_link_libraries(
    Server PUBLIC
    ImageDB
    /usr/local/lib64/libpqxx.a
    ${AWSSDK_LINK_LIBRARIES}
)
```

Comment: It's failing to link libcurl which isn't part of the aws sdk. You might need to add that to the target_link_libraries.

Comment: Do you have static version of libcurl installed? something like `libcurl.a` in /usr/lib or other linker search paths.